# How to find exact Time complexity and Space Complexity for below new Quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have created new sorting algorithm, The basic concept of this algorithm is finding smallest and Biggest element from given list 
and swapping them with left corner and right corner elements, this will be repeating until we reaches mid element.

This algorithm executing in very less time than Quick sort and merge sort. I want to make sure whether this algorithm performs better than Quick sort.

My Algorithm code

```
public class VeryQuickVersion1 
{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        long current = System.nanoTime();

        int[] first = { 8 ,1 ,3 ,2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 12 ,9, 11 ,10 ,14 ,13, 15};

        for (int x=0,y=first.length - 1;x<y;x++,y--) 
        {
            int low = 0;
            int high = 0;
            int li = 0;
            int hi = 0;
            for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) 
            {
                if (i == x)
                {
                    low = first[i];
                    high = first[i];
                }
                if (low > first[i]) 
                {
                    low = first[i];
                    li = i;
                }
                if (high < first[i])
                {
                    high = first[i];
                    hi = i;
                }
            }

            first[li]=first[x];
            first[hi]=first[y];

            first[x]=low;
            first[y]=high;
        }
    /*  for(int i:first){
            System.out.println(i);
        }*/
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - current);
     }
}
```

time taken by this algorithm is:10148
and
time taken by Quick Sort algorithm for the same list is:17498

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time complexity for the above algorithm seems to be `O(n^2)`.

As you can see there are 2 nested `for` loops. external one runs from `x = 0, y = n` to `x < y`, and in each step it reduces `x++` and `y--`. While the other inner loop goes from `x` to `y`.

This can be seen as a series `n + (n-2) + (n-4) + .... + 0`. Which clearly gives time complexity `O(n^2)`

---

Time complexity is not calculated the way you are doing. You should check how **the time taken by this program will increase when the size of the input is increased**. And test the same with **different type of inputs**, (ex ascending, random, etc).

After you have gathered the data for very large inputs and different types of inputs, then you will see the difference between algorithms that as `O(nlogn)` time complexity and algorithms that has `O(n^2)` time complexity.

---

**NOTE:** You can see the real difference how time taken increases in [this](https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/) website. Notice how time taken increases after the length of input increases to `50000`.

Comment: If we consider an array with 10 elements that will get executed in (10+8+6+4+2+0) 30 which is not equals to 10^2

Comment: If we consider an array with 10 elements that will get executed in (10+8+6+4+2+0) 30 which is not equals to 10^2 .so we can not say time complexity as n^2 right.

Comment: @damodaram, Thats not the way time complexity is calculated. `(n^2)` does not mean that program will take `n^2` seconds/minutes to execute. It means that the time taken by the program will increase in a quadratic manner with the increase in the number of inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You don't set benchmarks on any algorithm with such small data size. The size of your array is 10, which is really a small size.

Create an array of size ~10^5 or 10^6 and then check for the performance.

Also, just by looking at the code, I can tell that this algorithm is worse than Quick Sort. In asymptotic complexity, quick sort is O(n log n) while this one is clearly O(n^2).

I used Arrays.sort to sort the array using quick sort.

Here are the results:

Array size 1000

```
For Quick Sort algorithm:
1817634

For my algorithm:
8105038
```

Array size 100000

```
For Quick Sort algorithm:
21210010

For my algorithm:
7117304154
```

You can clearly see the difference.

My code, just for reference:
(For my algorithm, I just copied your code)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quick{

public static void main(String args[]) {


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();

    int[] first = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        first[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    int second[] = first.clone();

    long current = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(second);
    System.out.println("For Quick Sort algorithm:\n" + (System.nanoTime() - current) + "\n");

    current = System.nanoTime();

    for (int x=0,y=first.length - 1;x<y;x++,y--) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = 0;
        int li = 0;
        int hi = 0;
        for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
            if (i == x) {
                low = first[i];
                high = first[i];
            }
            if (low > first[i]) {
                low = first[i];
                li = i;
            }
            if (high < first[i]) {
                high = first[i];
                hi = i;
            }
        }

        first[li]=first[x];
        first[hi]=first[y];

        first[x]=low;
        first[y]=high;
    }
/*  for(int i:first){
        System.out.println(i);
    }*/
    System.out.println("For my algorithm:\n" + (System.nanoTime() - current));



 }
}
```

Comment: Performance vise my algorithm is worse but time complexity is not n^2

Comment: Why do you say so? Above answer by @Haris explains clearly, why it is O(n^2)